# Unexpected output in java

Tags: java

I have written a code -

```
// Node Class
class aNode {

    // Node Contents
    int NodeInt;
    char NodeChar;

    // constructor
    aNode() {
    }

    aNode(int x, char y) {
        NodeInt = x;
        NodeChar = y;
    }
}

class MainClass {

    static aNode node = new aNode();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        node = null;
        function(node);

        if (node == null) {
            System.out.println("Node is null");
        }
    }

    static void function(aNode x) {
        if (x == null) {
            System.out.println("Node is null");
        }

        x = new aNode(5, 'c');

        System.out.println(x.NodeInt);
        System.out.println(x.NodeChar);
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be -

```
Node is null
5
c
```

but when the program returns to main, the value of node is set to null again. So I get the output to be -

```
Node is null
5
c
Node is null
```

Please help me modify the code to get desired output. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [is-java-pass-by-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Real pass-by-reference is impossible in Java. Java passes everything by value, including references.**.
So you have to slightly change your code to get the desired output:

```
class aNode{

    //Node Contents
    int NodeInt;
    char NodeChar;

    //constructor
    aNode(){
    }
    aNode(int x, char y){
        NodeInt = x;
        NodeChar = y;
    }
}

class JavaApplication8{

    static aNode node = new aNode();

    public static void main(String[] args){


        node = null;
        node=function(node);

        if(node == null){
            System.out.println("Node is null");
        }
    }

    static aNode function(aNode x){
        if(x == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Node is null");
        }

        x = new aNode(5,'c');

        System.out.println(x.NodeInt);
        System.out.println(x.NodeChar);
        return x;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Node is null
5
c
```

Answer (score 3):

You should know, that `aNode node` and `aNode x` are references to different objects. It is one of Java features - passing **only** by value. It mean, that when you are calling

```
function(node);
```

you are not passing `node` reference to method `function(...)`, you are creating new reference to the same object. But in line

```
x = new aNode(5,'c');
```

you are setting reference `x` to new object. So, `node` *still* references to null and `x` references to new `aNode`.

To get more about passing params in Java, [read next article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into
>   methods by value. This means that when the method returns, the
>   passed-in reference still references the same object as before.
>   However, the values of the object's fields can be changed in the
>   method, if they have the proper access level.

Comment: that helped !! Now I used a return statement in functions that over-rides the value in main and it's fixed. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a static object, but in the method function(), you are not changing the value of object ***node***. You are changing the value of other object only. So in main, the value of ***node*** s null only.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is because Java passes a copy of the reference to the aNode object to your method. Changing this reference will not change the original reference.

Answer (score 0):

Inside function(), x is simply a local variable. When you reassign a reference in Java, you are modifying the content of the reference itself, not the one of the referred object. There's no way in Java to pass the address-of an object. If you want such a behavior, you can try with a generic class like Wrapper